# Console application user break

Tags: консоль, boost

Привет! Подскажите, у кого какие идеи, как можно решить. 
Есть консольное приложение. В нем выполняются разные вычисления, в отдельных потоках. Нужно организовать user break. Т. е. "жмякнув" **Esc**, вычисления и приложение завершаются. 
Идеи пока две, **SetWindowsHookEx(...)** и **boost::signal**.

Answer (score 1):

Как наипростейший вариант:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
for ( ; ; ) {

    // ... вычисления ...

    if ( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_ESCAPE ) & 0x8000 ) {

        // ...
        // подготовка к выходу
        // ...

        break;
    }

    // ... вычисления ...
}
return 0;
}
```

На самом деле всё зависит от потребностей. Вполне возможно, вариант с **SetWindowsHookEx** будет более подходящим.

Comment: Задал вопрос, потом вспомнил за эту функцию. Уже сделал. GetAsyncKeyState вполне хватает для решения поставленной задачи. Все равно большое спасибо за ответ и проявленный интерес к вопросу.